# How to populate all the values above to the table below once I click add button?

Tags: php, html-table

I have a problem is how to populate all the values above to the table below once I click add button.I am using php ,jquery and html to create it. Anyone can guide me how do it like below the picture? I have search in the internet to find the solution, but can't get it the solution. Below the picture is client show me want to create like this add table like below the picutre.
Hope someone can guide me or give me example to solve me the problem. Thanks.

[image: Output]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to create another row?

Comment: Just to be clear. You are using the form above to get your user inputs rights? Then processing it and adding it to your entries. This can be done multiple ways. Visually all you do is $(element).append().. but, likely you need to work with your database. So you will need to submit those values to your server. process them. and then return the data or html you will $(element).append(); or you can also re write all the rows.

Comment: So when you click the button, you want to add the values you entered in the input fields highlighted by the red square into the fields of the tables that are below?
Please add the html and relevant php that populates form and table. If you are NOT using JS or JQuery, I would stick with PHP as you are hitting the button to post the values likely, this can all be done with one technology in that case. If you want front end changes to populate the fields BEFORE you hit the Add button this would require JS or JQuery. I assume you want to stick to PHP yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, see if fits your needs:

HTML:

```
<form role="form">
  <label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label for="age"></label>
  <input type="number" id="age">
  <label for="gender"></label>
  <input type="text" id="gender">
</form>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Felipe</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addButton">Add</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){

  var newTableRow = '<tr><td>'+ $('#name').val() +'</td><td>'+ $('#age').val() +'</td><td>'+ $('#gender').val() +'</td></tr>';

  $('#table tr:last').after(newTableRow);  
})
```

This script can be triggered as you click the button to save the data or after the response from your back-end.